# How to find return type of a method in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

Could anyone help me find the return type of a method in Java. I tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Please guide me.

```java
Method testMethod = master.getClass().getMethod("getCnt");
    
if (!"int".equals(testMethod.getReturnType())) {
    System.out.println("not int ::" + testMethod.getReturnType());
}
```

**Output :**

```
not int ::int
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method `getReturnType()` returns `Class`

You can try:

```
if (testMethod.getReturnType().equals(Integer.TYPE)){ 
      .....;  
}
```

Comment: Its usually good convention to reverse the equals to avoid potential NPEs when equating instances against known constants (ie `Integer.TYPE.equals(testmethod.getReturnType())`)

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!int.class == testMethod.getReturnType())
{
  System.out.println("not int ::"+testMethod.getReturnType());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The return type is a `Class<?>`... to get a string try:

```
  if(!"int".equals(testMethod.getReturnType().getName()))
   {
      System.out.println("not int ::"+testMethod.getReturnType());
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

`getReturnType()` returns `Class<?>` rather than a `String`, so your comparing is incorrect.

Either

```java
Integer.TYPE.equals(testMethod.getReturnType())
```

Or

```java
int.class.equals(testMethod.getReturnType())
```

Answer (score 1):

`getReturnType()` return a Class object, and you are comparing to a string.
You can try

```
if(!"int".equals(testMethod.getReturnType().getName() ))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getReturnType` method returns a `Class<?>` object not a `String` one which you are comparing it with. A `Class<?>` object will never be equal to a `String` object.

In order to compare them you have to use

`!"int".equals(testMethod.getReturnType().toString())`

Answer (score 1):

getretunType() returns `Class<T>`. You can test it for being equal to type of Integer

```
if (testMethod.getReturnType().equals(Integer.TYPE)) {
    out.println("got int");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use getretunType() to return a Class object, and then compare it with "int".equals（...）

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).