# Refactoring by passing generic method

Tags: java, generics, reflection, refactoring

I have simplified my code to this:

```
static private String waitForString(String expected, int attempts) {
  String actual = null;
   for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++){
      actual = getString();
      if (validateString(actual, expected)) {
         return actual;
      }
   }
   return null;
}

static private int waitForInt(int expected, int attempts) {
   int actual = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++){
      actual = getInt();
      if (validateInt(actual, expected)) {
         return actual;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Since I'm using the same loop (and since I have more than one class with more than one corresponding "getter" method and validation method) I would like to refactor it. I tried this:

```
static <T> T helperMethod(Method getMethod, Method validator,T expected, int attempts) {
   T actual = null;
   for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++){
      actual = method.invoke(null);
      if (validator.invoke(null, actual, expected)) {
         return actual;
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

However I'm getting following errors:

```
actual = method.invoke(null);
error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to T 

validator.invoke(null, actual, expected)
error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to boolean
```

Can I specify in the function declaration only to accept methods with the correct return type? If so, how? 
Ideas for other ways to refactor will be appreciated.

EDITED
To make it clear, I wasnt asking how reflect the return type of the method. 
Thanks you VGR for the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find return type of a Method in JAVA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730223/how-to-find-return-type-of-a-method-in-java)

Comment: @DmytroGrynets What does it means with the OP question?

Comment: He could find out method's return type inside his method and check it

Comment: You need casts, as `Method.invoke` returns an `Object`. You could use Java8 functional interfaces instead of `Method`, but to have 1 generic method your `int`s would need to be boxed.

Comment: If using Java 8 I'd suggest going for functional interfaces and avoid using reflection. Use `Supplier` for passing the next value and `Predicate` for validation. Or use the Streams API if possible. Where do the Strings initially come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use reflection.

Reflection is slower, hard for a developer (including yourself) to follow, and cannot be checked by the compiler for correct arguments and return type.

The correct way to accomplish the equivalent of a “pointer to a method” in Java is to wrap the various method calls in a common interface.  As of Java 8, as Markus Benko pointed out, you should use suppliers and predicates:

```
static <T> T waitForValue(Supplier<T> getMethod, BiPredicate<T, T> validator, T expected, int attempts) {
   T actual = null;
   for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++){
      actual = getMethod.get();
      if (validator.test(actual, expected)) {
         return actual;
      }
   }
   return null;
}

private static String waitForString(String expected, int attempts) {
    return waitForValue(ThisClass::getString, ThisClass::validateString, expected, attempts);
}

private static int waitForInt(int expected, int attempts) {
    return waitForValue(ThisClass::getInt, ThisClass::validateInt, expected, attempts);
}
```

If you’re using an older version of Java, you can do the same thing with a little more work:

```
private interface Getter<T> {
    T get();
}

private interface Validator<T> {
    boolean test(T actual, T expected);
}

static <T> T waitForValue(Getter<T> getMethod, Validator<T> validator, T expected, int attempts) {
   T actual = null;
   for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++){
      actual = getMethod.get();
      if (validator.test(actual, expected)) {
         return actual;
      }
   }
   return null;
}

private static String waitForString(String expected, int attempts) {
    Getter<String> getter = new Getter<String>() {
        @Override
        public String get() {
            return getString();
        }
    };
    Validator<String> validator = new Validator<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(String actual, String expected) {
            return validateString(actual, expected);
        }
    };
    return waitForValue(getter, validator, expected, attempts);
}

private static int waitForInt(int expected, int attempts) {
    Getter<Integer> getter = new Getter<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer get() {
            return getInt();
        }
    };
    Validator<Integer> validator = new Validator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Integer actual, Integer expected) {
            return validateInt(actual, expected);
        }
    };
    return waitForValue(getter, validator, expected, attempts);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using reflection for different reasons: loose of JVM optimizations, your code compiles but explodes at runtime, the code is hard to be debugged.

You can try by creating an interface with the implementations for each type you need to validate.

Something like:

**Interface:**

```
public interface InputHandler<T> {
  Boolean wait(T expected);
}
```

**Implementations:**

*An handler implementation for the input String:*

```
public class StringHandler implements InputHandler<String> {
    @Override
    public Boolean wait(String expected) {
        String actual = getString();
        return validateString(actual, expected);
    }

    private String getString() {
        // ...
        return null;
    }

    private boolean validateString(String actual, String expected) {
        // ...
        return false;
    }
}
```

*An handler implementation for the input Integer:*

```
public class IntegerHandler implements InputHandler<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Boolean wait(Integer expected) {
        Integer actual = getInt();
        return validateInt(actual, expected);
    }

    private boolean validateInt(Integer actual, Integer expected) {
        // ...
        return false;
    }

    private Integer getInt() {
        // ...
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can add and remove all the "handlers" you need really fast.

**App to run the example:**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        waitForValidInput(new StringHandler(), "a", 3);
        waitForValidInput(new IntegerHandler(), 5, 3);
    }

    static private <T> T waitForValidInput(InputHandler<T> validator, T expected, int attempts) {
        for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++) {
            if(validator.wait(expected)) {
                return expected;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: What with `Boolean` instead of `boolean`? `wait` could be remove from `InputHandler` leaving the `private` methods `public`. Probably the `get` and `validate` methods could be different functors, though that diverges from teh original question. (I'm not a fan of low meaning types such as `BiPredicate`. I mean, eurgh.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static <T> T helperMethod(Method method, Method validator, T expected, int attempts) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    T actual = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++) {
        actual = (T)method.invoke(null);
        if ((Boolean)validator.invoke(null, actual, expected)) {
            return actual;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

(also added exceptions in the signature and changed `getMehod` to `method` in the arguments)

Comment: Avoid using reflection. It is not a good practice. The problem can be solved in other ways.