# How can I call interface methods by their return type

Tags: java

I can declare an `InterfaceA`, which can contain any methods. But important to say, that it must contain methods (they are required by framework), that return `Return<T extends Data>`. Each `T` is present only once and there no method that return `Data` itself:

```
class InterfaceA {
    Return<DataA> returnData...(...);
    Return<DataB> returnData...(...);
    ...
}
```

And I have ClassB:

```
class ClassB<T extends Data> {
    InterfaceA a;

    void process() {
        Return<T> data = a.returnData(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

I need some way to pick proper method from `InterfaceA` dependently on type `T` of `ClassB`. How can I do that?

Comment: Provided that the argument lists of the two `returnData(...)` declarations are the same, your interface won't compile.

Comment: Change methods to returnDataA and returnDataB

Comment: Yes, they can have any name, and any arguments, only return type matters.

Comment: At runtime - you don't know what the real `T` is unless you are given either a class object or a concrete object of that type. That's what type erasure is all about. So unless you are passed a "type token" of some sort, there is no way to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730223/how-to-find-return-type-of-a-method-in-java

Comment: That's a terrible pattern to find yourself in, and unless all subclasses of `Data` have distinct lineages (i.e. none of it is a parent of another), there is no way out of it really.

Comment: As biziclop has indicated, the real solution is not to solve the problem as presented but to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it  by having a method in the interface that will return the type of the Object that extends data and then use some if statements or a switch-case to then run a method depending on what this method returns.

Eg.

```
public class Test extends Data{

private final String identifier;

public Test(String identifier){

this.identifier = identifier;

}
public String getIdentifier(){

return identifier;

}
}
```

Not sure if that's any help bro as others said it's not the best design pattern.

Comment: I think the point you are missing is that when the `process` method is called, there is no object that extends `Data`. The method is supposed to get such an object, based on the type bound to the class's `T` and return that.